# How to match the values of two columns(same table) in diagonal and display the result when they don't match

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a `city` table that has two columns

```
from_city
to_city
```

now lets assume that one row has the following values

```
'lahore'
'peshawar'
```

and the next row has

```
'peshawar'
'lahore'
```

Notice that the values match diagonally. I want to display all the rows that don't match in such a manner.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this perhaps:

```
SELECT * 
FROM bus_route b1 
LEFT JOIN bus_route b2 ON b1.from_city=b2.to_city AND b1.to_city=b2.from_city
WHERE b2.from_city IS NULL
```

Comment: any ideas on how we mite do the same thing without using joins?

Comment: Why would you want to avoid the joins?

Comment: Joins usually slow things down considerably when dealing with a large amount of data