# How to store the result of a query into an sql variable

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'd like to save the result of the following query in an sql variable and than subtract that variable from the main table city to get my desired result.

```
SELECT *
FROM
city b1,city b2
WHERE
b1.from_city = b2.to_city
and b1.to_city = b2.from_city
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Which column are you trying to subtract? You cannot subtract record sets...

Comment: this query gives me two columns and i'd like to subtract both these columns from my main table city

Comment: Perhaps some example data would help?

Comment: The nature of the problem and example data is provided at the following link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9869526/how-to-match-the-values-of-two-columnssame-table-in-diagonal-and-display-the-r

Comment: The problem had been solved using join, now i'm trying to solve it without using it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems like you want to remove(in output) the rows having destination in  circular form ..

if I am getting right then you can use following query -

```
select * from city a 
where not exists 
(select 1 from city b where b.from_city=a.to_city and b.to_city = a.from_city
)
```